# Subsetting data using grep

Tags: r

I have a dataframe named Schedule which has data for multiple airlines. I run the table function just to get the breakdown of records by airlines. Here is the answer

```
table(Schedule$airline)

 AA  AS  B6  BA  DL  F9  FI  LH  NK  QR  UA  WN 
757   4  14   2  65  24   2   2  18   2  36  60
```

Now I am subsetting this data using grep to get a data frame which has gates in a particular terminal of interest, which in this case is terminal F

```
Gated_Schedule <- Schedule[grep("F", Schedule$gate), ]
```

when I run table to get a breakdown here,

```
table(Gated_Schedule$airline)

 AA  AS  B6  BA  DL  F9  FI  LH  NK  QR  UA  WN 
362   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Ideally the output should only have been `AA` like:

```
 AA  
362
```

How do I get rid of this discrepancy?

Comment: what is the structure of your data frame? (i.e. `str(Gated_Schedule)`)...

Comment: I would bet that `airline` is stored as a `factor`, and you want it to be a `character`